# Стоит ли в целях повышения производительности избегать импорта ES6-классов, если от них используется лишь один-два метода?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Допустим, я импортировал ES6-класс, но мне нужно от него только метод или два. Какое отрицательное влияние на моё приложение окажут те свойства и методы импортированного класса, которые не используются?

Учитывая, что ещё применяется babel, думаю что ответ на вопрос будет актуален и для JavaScript-объектов.

Comment: свойства и методы из импорта, которые ты не используешь, просто загрязнят твой глобал.

Comment: Возможно что при использовании webpack или rollup они даже и не попадут в код, так как будут убраны через TreeShake или Dead Code Elimination .

Comment: Но лучше конечно сразу же эти методы и импортировать, так 100% лишнего кода не будет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, rollup тут не поможет,  так как он не может выдрать часть класса.

Comment: Влияние свойств и методов импортированного класса зависит от этих самых свойств и методов. Почему они вообще должны оказывать какое-то влияние? почему ты думаешь, что используя один или два публичных метода класса, внутри себя они не могут использовать что-то еще? То есть, ты думаешь, что используется только метод. а на самом деле используется весь класс

Comment: @Grundy как делает rollup я не знаю, но теоретически неиспользуемые функции можно убрать, даже если они внутри методов используются это можно определить. Да, я не спорю, просто размышляю.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, собственно rollup работает на уровне модулей, а не классов. На самом деле неиспользуемые функции определить в общем случае нельзя, из-за возможности использования `bracket notation`

Comment: @Grundy да, ясно, спасибо, `скобочно кавычные выражения` всю малину портят.

Comment: @Grundy оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ