# Засоряют ли глобальную область расширения стандартных JS-объектов?

Tags: javascript

Как известно, в JavaScript можно расширять стандартные объекты, например:

```
Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
    return 32 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
};
```

Теперь предположим, что я или кто-то другой создал библиотеку с тысячами таких расширений. Из вопроса [стоит ли в целях повышения производительности избегать импорта ES6-классов, если от них используется лишь один-два метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794949/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-es6-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8), я уже узнал, что неиспользуемые функции и классы засоряют глобальную область. 
Относится ли это к расширениям стандартных объектов? Правильно ли я понял, что эти расширения также будут засорять глобальную область?

Comment: Глобальная область - это всего лишь список автодополнения. Который появляется, когда начинаешь печатать что-то в консоли браузера или IDE. Конечно, будут, как и вообще любые функции. Главная проблема этих расширений совсем в другом.

Comment: @SmInc, ну так Вы объясните. Если бы я всё знал, я бы здесь вопросов не задавал.

Comment: @SmInc, в чём именно?

Comment: Вот то и плохо, что сами догадаться не можете :) А проблема расширений стандартных классов или объектов - в хаосе, который при этом создается в коде. Создается ощущение, что эти функции стандартно входят в эти классы или объекты.

Comment: _я уже узнал, что неиспользуемые функции и классы засоряют глобальную область_ - ты сделал неправильные выводы. При импорте ничего не засоряется.

Comment: Сначала дай определение того, что ты считаешь _глобальной областью_. В соответствии с твоим определением сразу станет видно - засоряют или нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*расширение* стандартных объектов, заключается в изменении их прототипа.

Прототип стандартных объектов не является глобальной областью видимости.

Следовательно: *расширение* стандартных объектов не засоряют *глобальную область*.

---

Проблема в расширении стандартных объектов, в том, что ты не можешь точно знать, какая именно реализация будет использована, если две библиотеки будут добавлять методы с одинаковым называнием и, вполне возможно, разной реализацией.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. А какое будет влияние на производительность, если этих расширений очень много? Понятно, что потери при загрузке с сервера кода, где эти расширения реализованы... Далее небольшие потери на разрешение идентификаторов... Что ещё?

Comment: @БоковГлеб, очень много - это сколько?

Comment: Ну, предположим, что как минимум штук 1000. Мне же их не обязательно все самому писать.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, тогда ты вряд ли на глаз заметишь потерю производительности.